# java windowbuilder can't add bindings for columns

Tags: eclipse, swing, binding, javabeans, windowbuilder

I am trying to bind an ArrayList of objects to a jTable using Eclipse WindowsBuilder. 
But Create Data Binding screen doesn't show "Add" button, as is shown in eclipse tutorial.

Here is my object:

```
public class EventDTO implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private String comment;
private Date date;
private String message;
private Set<EventGiftDTO> eventGifts;
private Set<EventPersonDTO> participants;
private Set<EventProductDTO> eventProducts;
private PersonDTO initiator;
private EventTypeDTO eventType;

public EventDTO() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getComment() {
    return this.comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return this.date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Set<EventGiftDTO> getGifts() {
    return eventGifts;
}

public void setGifts(Set<EventGiftDTO> eventGifts) {
    this.eventGifts = eventGifts;
}

public boolean addGift(EventGiftDTO eg){
    if(eventGifts==null)eventGifts=new HashSet<>();
    return eventGifts.add(eg);
}

public boolean removeGift(EventGiftDTO adv){
    if(eventGifts==null) return true;
    return eventGifts.remove(adv);
}

public Set<EventPersonDTO> getParticipants() {
    return participants;
}

public void setParticipants(Set<EventPersonDTO> participants) {
    this.participants = participants;
}

public boolean addParticipant(EventPersonDTO p){
    if(participants==null) participants=new HashSet<>();
    return participants.add(p);
}

public boolean removeParticipant(EventPersonDTO p){
    if(participants==null) return true;
    return participants.remove(p);
}

public Set<EventProductDTO> getProducts() {
    return eventProducts;
}

public void setProducts(Set<EventProductDTO> eventProducts) {
    this.eventProducts = eventProducts;
}

public boolean addProduct(EventProductDTO pr){
    if(eventProducts==null) eventProducts=new HashSet<>();
    return eventProducts.add(pr);
}

public boolean removeProduct(EventProductDTO pr){
    if(eventProducts==null) return true;
    return eventProducts.remove(pr);
}

public PersonDTO getInitiator() {
    return initiator;
}

public void setInitiator(PersonDTO initiator) {
    this.initiator = initiator;
}

public EventTypeDTO getEventType() {
    return eventType;
}

public void setEventType(EventTypeDTO eventType) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
}
```

}

and here is my Create Data Binding screen:

[Create Data Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyHRT.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Well, i also was thinking that i am doing something wrong. But, when i imported a sample project from here: [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.swing.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ffeatures%2Fswing%2Fdata_binding%2Fexample.html) and tried to Edit Data Binding for the table, i also couldn't see these buttons. It looks like a bug, or may be i am missing some libraries?!